# Spring-boot не находит страницы в папке templates?

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь запустить spring-boot с использованием страницы `greeting.html` в папке `src/main/resources/templates`, но вместо страницы выводится просто текст `greeting`

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

Собираю мавеном. Результат одинаковый, что из IDE, что из командной строки.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Шаблонизатор в зависимостях проекта есть? 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Да, шаблонищатор указал. Обязательно thymeleaf использовать или можно файлы их других шаблонизаторов тоже в папку templates складывать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для решения проблемы нужно было добавить зависимость на thymeleaf, изменить html шаблон соответствующим образам (т.е. на корректным образом сформированную thymeleaf-шаблон) и поменять аннотацию `@RestController` (является сочетанием аннотаций `@Controller` и `@ResponseBody`) на `@Controller` (обозначает что данный класс является котроллером в модели Spring MVC).

[При работе со Spring Boot не рекомендуется использовать jsp, так как jsp не будет работать со спринг бутом (только из варника).](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)

Comment: Вообще-то работает ;)

Answer (score 0):

Текст greeting будет выводится потому что ты поставил @RestController
Для html нужен просто @Controller
Ты мог забыть добавить зависимость freemarker

Comment: Автор вопроса сам дал ответ на свой вопрос. Вы его прочли? Если да, то укажите, пожалуйста, прямо в ответе - что даёт нового ваше решение, какие его преимущества?